# JQuery class added does not persist on change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I just can't figure out a behaviour, i am not a JQuery guru and this gives me headache.
So, on my document ready i have

```
 $('#Table').on('change', '#TeamValue', function (event) {
        $(this).removeClass("valid");
        $(this).addClass("input-validation-error");
        var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log(myClass);
    }
});
```

In console i see the class changed but on front it is not. Why is this happening?
Also i have seen that when i delete the content my input-validation-error class appear well... i just dont understand.
Can anybody give me a hand?

Thanks!

Input before class change:

```
<input  id='TeamValue' type='text' class='small-textbox'>
```

Console log:

```
text:a -.js:451:1
wroing! -.js:456:13
small-textbox input-validation-error
```

HTML of that element after his class was changed:

```
<input id="TeamValue" onkeyup="Restriction()" class="small-textbox valid" type="text">
```

Comment: Do you mean that the css associated with that class is not taking effect?  Also, can you post some of the html?

Comment: I have added more details in the first post. The class is somehow deleted after my function is ended and i dont know how...

Comment: From what you have there it looks correct.  Is there code elsewhere which could be interfering?

Answer (score -1):

The `$(this)` context you are referring to is likely the `#Table` element and not the `#TeamValue` element you are expecting. My assumption is that the class changes are occurring on that element instead. Try attaching the change handler directly to the `#TeamValue` element:

```
$('#TeamValue').on('change', function (event) {
    $(this).removeClass("valid");
    $(this).addClass("input-validation-error");
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(myClass);
});
```

```

Comment: That is not true.  The this pointer is referencing #TeamValue.  Though he probably should change the bind to match what you put but only because he is using an ID and might as well take advantage of that.